# Unity Facebook SDK & Chartboost AndriodManifest activity conflict

Tags: android, facebook, chartboost, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using both Facebook and Chartboost SDK for Unity on Android. Both works fine individually. But when they are built in the same project, the activity for facebook -"com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity" and the activity for chartboost- "com.chartboost.sdk.unity.CBUnityPlayerProxyActivity" conflicted, because they need the same place. I wonder what is the solution to make both plug-in work together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our main activity is only for those who aren't using other plugins who also want the main activity.

In order for activities to play nice with each other, the better thing to do in your case is to create a class that extends `CBUnityPlayerProxyActivity` and add:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This will pass data to the Facebook SDK correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The data will pass to the SDK,but how about the Class Name filed in facebook app page, should I fill with com.chartboost.sdk.unity.CBUnityPlayerProxyActivity ?

Comment: You should fill it with your main activity.  If that's your main activity then put that in.